# Multithreading in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
FuncToBeParallelized
{
    Param ([string] $groupID)
    ...
}

foreach ($item in $groupData.asset_groups) {
    # Fetching a list of assets using group_id
    $groupID = $item.Item("id").ToString()
    $result = FuncToBeParallelized $groupID
}
```

$groupData.asset_groups has around 3000 entries. So, it's impossible to 
spawn 3000 threads at a time to complete all the tasks.

So, is there a way to do 'n tasks' (say n=20) in parallel at a 
time and continue doing all the remaining tasks once these n tasks have 
been completed?

Comment: You should use Runspaces. http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2017/02/22/multithreading-with-powershell-using-runspacepool.aspx